# Is there any order compilation flags should appear?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I want to compile a C file that only has a function to assembly.

To compile, I'm running the following command

```
clang -c -m32 -O1 -S exemple.c
```

Everything works fine but I was wondering if there is any convention regarding the order of which compilation flags should appear.

Comment: Unless you're part of a group project or open source with existing standards, the best convention is usually to pick what works well for you and use it consistently.

Comment: Why are you using both -S and -c? I'm pretty sure that -S wins out regardless of order, on the logic that -S causes translation to stop before -c does anything, but I wouldn't want to bet that every compiler version handles that combination the same way.

Comment: Note that in some cases linker order _does_ matter.

Comment: Some of the switches/flags for which order affects the behavior of the compiler are those for specifying paths to search for included or library files and the `-x` switch for specifying the language to interpret the following files in. Also, the order of specifying library files matters, since library files and object modules (either specified directly or resulting from compilation of source files) are processed in the order they (or their source files) appear on the command line, and modules are taken from libraries only to satisfied pending references (unless modified by switches)…

Comment: … Library file names are not “flags” the compiler as asked, except that they can be specified with the “-l” switch. There may be others.